# Luggage lockers at Jardin Majorelle in Marrakech?

Tags: luggage-storage, morocco, marrakech

Can I leave my luggage at the garden while visiting? If not, would I be allowed to take a suitcase inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that, as of December 2015, the only public luggage lockers in the city Marrakech can be found:

- At the ONCF railway station, [according to this Routard thread (in French)](http://www.routard.com/forum_message/1335582/consigne_a_bagages_a_marrakech.htm)
- At the Supratours bus station, [according to this Voyage Forum thread (in French)](http://voyageforum.com/discussion/maroc-trouver-consigne-bagages-marrakech-d3432361/)
- At the *Gare Routière* (bus station) at Bab Doukkala, ibid.
- At the CTM bus station, [according to this Yahoo answers thread (in French)](https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070309063030AATSlW2)

The other option is to ask your hotel to keep your luggage after you check-in. If you are planning on visiting the Jardin before checking-in I will also suggest that you show up to your hotel and ask them to store the luggage for you.

Now I don't know if you can enter the Jardin with a suitcase. You can always try.